# Java SQL Querying With TextFields

Tags: java, sql

I wrote a SQL query and used textfield for getting data. But when is a textfield empty, it gives all data. How can i stop that? Here is my code:

```
String sql = "select * from boek where naam like '%" 
           + txtNaam.getText() + "%' or auteur like '%"
           + txtAuteur.getText() + "%' or categorie like '%" 
           + txtCategorie.getText() + "%' or opleiding like '%"
           + txtOpleiding.getText() + "%' not opleiding like '%" 
           + txtOpleiding.getText() + "%' ";
```

Comment: Don't allow the field to be empty.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk If i search a book, i do not have to know the name of the author. That is why i allow another textfields to be empty. But thanx anyway.

Comment: One your user input may be `%'; DROP DATABASE ...` and then...

Comment: Unrelated, but very  important nonetheless: do ***not*** concatenate user input. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Searching like that is better done using the full text search capabilities of your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking to query only with text field(s) that has value and ignore the rest that are empty.

My suggestion will be:

1) Write your java logics to determine what are the inputs from your program first.
e.g. author, category which are selected fields and not empty.

2) Run dedicated sql queries that facilitate search for ONLY the inputs selected.
e.g. in this case, SELECT using only author and category

So, there will be a few SQL queries there. Not only one that handles everything. That will be less confusing in my opinion. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanx @DriLLFreAK100 , i wanted to choose your answer, but i dont have enough point.

Comment: @Atti No worries. Glad that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

How about -

```
String sql = "select * from boek where ";
sql = addLike(sql, null, naam", txtNaam.getText());
sql = addLike(sql, "OR", auteur", txtAuteur.getText());
...


String addLike(String sql, String op, String col, String arg) {
if (arg != null && arg.length() > 0) {
    return sql + " " + (op == null ? "" : op) + " " + col + " like '%" + arg + "%' " ;
}
```

Excuse the syntax issues.
Btw, you might need input validations to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

A way you could approach this issue is by prior to sending your SQL query doing a check to see if your text field is empty. You can then send the query if they're all populated or refrain from doing so if they're not.

Here's an example of some code that should work:

```
if(!txtNaam.getText().equals("") && !txtAuteur.getText().equals("") && !txtCategorie.getText().equals("") && !txtOpleiding.getText().equals("") && !txtOpleiding.getText().equals("")){

    String sql = "select * from boek where naam like '%" + txtNaam.getText() + "%' or auteur like '%" 
        + txtAuteur.getText() + "%' or categorie like '%" + txtCategorie.getText() + "%' or opleiding like '%" 
        + txtOpleiding.getText() + "%' not opleiding like '%" + txtOpleiding.getText() + "%' ";

    //Execute query here

} else {

    //Code that will run if any values aren't available

}
```

Hope this helps!